# jqGrid - What are the options available for ColumnChooser dialog_opts

Tags: jqgrid

I would like the column chooser to appear at the top of the screen instead of the title bar being placed in the center of the screen (I have a lot of columns). I see there are some options available in dialog_opts but I can't find any documentation on them.

Is there an option I can select for dialog_opts to place the modal dialogue at the top of the screen?

I fixed this by updating the CSS as follows:
`div.ui-dialog.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-all.ui-front.ui-dialog-buttons.ui-draggable.ui-resizable {
                                top: 30px !important;
                    }`

Comment: The problem with this CSS is that when you move the columnChooser dialog, you can only move it left and right. Top is fixed at 30px.

Comment: @Oleg: Do you have the answer to this?